# Login timeout for domain-connected laptops

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012, login

I have Windows 7 laptops that are in the domain network, but are brought home with techs in case they need to work remotely.

Login times for those laptops are extremely slow when they are not connected to the domain network (ie. from home), as they get stuck on "Please wait for the user profile service", sometimes up to five minutes.

I know that this is because the machine is trying to locate a domain controller, but what I can't figure out is how to lower the timeout for it to use cached credentials. I would very much prefer not to use a VPN since this only applies to 2-3 laptops.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are your users logging in with roaming profiles? In a default configuration, domain member computers shouldn't take very long at all to logon without connectivity to a DC.

Comment: I agree with @twisty it does not look like it is waiting for a domain controller because it passed that point and it is trying to load the user profile.

Comment: Do you potentially have UE-V loaded on your laptops, or some sort of persona / profile management tool? I've seen this issue with UE-V specifically because the profile is stored in the users home folder and if the users home folder isn't made available offline, it takes a while to time out.

Comment: @twisty roaming profiles are not turned on.

Comment: @Eric C. Singer no profile management tools. Clean windows 7 installs and a clean server 2012 install.

Answer (score -1):

https://serverfault.com/a/456752

User environment debug logging may be useful in this scenario.